# Is there a max function for timestamps (with or without timezone)?

Tags: postgresql

When I call `max` on two timestamps, I get an error :

```sql
select max(now()::timestamp, to_timestamp('2021-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp);
-- ERROR:  function max(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
```

My actual usage would be in an upsert query, where I would like to write :

```
INSERT ...
ON CONFLICT (pk) DO UPDATE SET
  ts = max(table.ts, excluded.ts)
```

**Question**

Is there an idiomatic way to take the max between two timestamps in PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `greatest()` function.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=17c85cf021cc26a70f2df47d02e1622c)

`max()` ([link to docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.13.1.1.1)) is an aggregate function which returns the greatest value of a group of records.
`greatest()` ([link to docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)) takes the greatest value of an arbitrary number of parameters - two in your case. It can be used for type `timestamp` as well.

---

*extra note* : the function to take the smallest value of an arbitrary number of parameters is named `least()` ([same link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)) (not "smallest")

Answer (score 4):

Use `GREATEST`:

```sql
SELECT GREATEST(now()::timestamp, to_timestamp('2021-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp);
```

The `GREATEST` scalar function takes one or more arguments and returns the largest value of those inputs.